# AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_related_objects'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to implement https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz in my project.

When I run this command on Windows PowerShell:

```
py manage.py runserver
```

I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\model_utils\managers.py", 
line 106, in _get_subclasses_recurse
rel for rel in model._meta.get_all_related_objects()
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute     
'get_all_related_objects'
```

Comment: can you provide code for DB query ?

Comment: I was simply running server :  py manage.py runserver

Answer (score 2):

`django_quiz` has a dependent package `django-model-utils`.
`django-model-utils` supports `django==1.8` to `django==1.10` only.
Probably you are using latest version of `django`.
Downgrade the package django to `django==1.9` or `django==1.10`.
Then it will work.

For more information visit and read https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils